# How to access a file in Processing Android Mode

Tags: android, processing, assets, mode

I am trying to access a file in Processing Android Mode using the following:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
```

And I tried the following options for setting filePath for the file “1.sf2” in the “data” folder that I created in the current sketch directory. However, none of them worked.

```
filePath = dataPath(“1.sf2”);
filePath = sketchPath(“data/1.sf2”);
filePath = sketchPath(“assets/1.sf2”);
filePath = “data/1.sf2”;
filePath = “assets/1.sf2”;
```

According to the github page of Processing Android Mode, everying file in the “data” folder of the current sketch directory are automatically copied to the “assets” folder of the generated apk file. However, I keep getting “java.io.FileNotFoundException: /null/restore_pixels: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)” exception every time I run the application on my Android device.

Is there a way to correctly access a file in Processing Android Mode? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide the real values for `filePath` as we dont know where sketchPath(...) would evaluate to. Or what a sketch directory would be.

Comment: And this Processing Android Mode (never heard of) is at compile time? Why didnt you tell?

Comment: Android Mode is a mode for Processing: https://android.processing.org/. I am using the Processing software (Android Mode) to compile the apk file and install the compiled apk to the Android device. sketchPath() is a function that is provided by Processing to obtain the path of the root of a Processing sketch.

Comment: You have not told the full paths values of `filePath`.

Comment: `File file = new File(filePath);` Is that code executed in Processing Mode (as you say) or at runtime by your Android app?

Comment: since the application (sketch) is running on the Android device, I could not obtain the value of filePath in the device. I could run the application (sketch) on my computer, but the filePath value is not the same as in the Android device

Comment: Well i asked you what the paths were on Android device. And you still did not tell.

Comment: i believe this code is executed at runtime by Android

Comment: since the application (sketch) is running on the Android device, I could not obtain the value of filePath in the device.

Comment: Why not? You can Toast() them. You can Log.d() them. Tou can put hem in a TextView. What is the problem?

Comment: `File file = new File(filePath);` Are you really trying to handle a in this way a file in assets resource at runtime in your Android app?

Comment: I am using the "Processing" software to develop an application, in this software it does not recognize the class "Toast" or "Log". For example, it gives me: Toast cannot be resolved error

Comment: There is no path and you cannot use the File class. It is unclear what you want. Open the file or check if it is there in assets?

Comment: I think the problem can be reduced to how to find the correct path of "1.sf2" which is in "assets" in ordinary Android development? Or if there is another way to access this file other than using a file path, then it's ok as well. is there another way to do this?

Comment: I need to create a File object of "1.sf2" in order to run "Soundbank soundbank = MidiSystem.getSoundbank(file);"

Comment: You can get an input stream for a file in assets with InputStream is = getAssets().open("1.sf2");

Comment: `I need to create a File object of "1.sf2" in order to run "Soundbank soundbank = MidiSystem.getSoundbank(file);"` You have never said that before. And you never told what you all wanted,

Comment: `You can list all files in assets with String files[] = getAssets().list(""); `

Comment: I used the getContext().getAssets().list("")[0] as the "File file", but it still gives me the "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /null/restore_pixels: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)" error